# Store ID in a session, redirect to a new page and display content based on the session

Tags: c#, session

I am working on a solution where I have a gridview displaying a list of my records. When you click on one you get redirected to a details page, I have created a session which only stores the ID. All that works fine.

My question is: How do I fetch the rest of the data on the new page? Is it possible this way or do I need to store all the values in a session?

Comment: What rest of data you wanna show on detail page ?

Comment: You sure this is about C#? Sounds like web stuff to me. Anyway, when dealing with web data, you have to pass it to the next page some way or another. Either store it in the session, pass it by GET or POST. If you have a database backup, you just have to pass the ID of the data you want to show and query the database (again) to fetch it.

Comment: I think the problem is if how to store ID then access the ID to another or new page.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Session.Add(ID, valueOfID);
```

you can access it through:

```
string str = (string)Session[ID];
```

Comment: if your id `string` use string if `int` then use int as datatype. Cast the datatype to your Session to avoid error.